# how to auto populate lookup field value based on record type?

Tags: lookup, record-type

How to populate lookup field value based on record type without using code. i have tired with lookup field filter but there is no record type functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Lookup field filters do not populate data. They only filter available values for a user populating the lookup field or apply constraints to the values that can be added there.

You can easily achieve this objective using Process Builder. Simply set the criteria on your action node to filter based upon the record type. Then add an "Update Records" immediate action and choose the record that started your process. Add a record update entry for the lookup field and populate the appropriate value.

This works for cases where the lookup field should be populated with a constant, an entry stored in custom settings (Process Builder formulas can reference Custom Settings), or a reference to an object that's already related to the source object. If you need to perform a query to locate the record you want to lookup to, you'll have to have your Process call an autolaunched Flow to perform that query.